# Redundant button on election pages with less than three candidates

Tags: bug, election

I noticed this minor UX bug on the ongoing [Open Source SE election page](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/election): Each candidate in an SE election page has three buttons next to their candidacy - 1st choice, 2nd choice and 3rd choice. However, the Open Source SE elections just have two candidates, so having a "3rd choice" doesn't serve any useful function.

Definitely not the most important bug in the world, but I figured I might as well report it.

Screenshot:
[image]